# sql server incorrect checksum error on deployment

Tags: sql-server, installation

When I try to start the Sql Server (SqlExpress) service I got the following message:

I've looked at the log file (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG) and find out the following lines:

> 2010-03-09 06:12:35.51 spid7s Error: 824, Severity: 24, State: 2.
>   2010-03-09 06:12:35.51 spid7s SQL
>   Server detected a logical
>   consistency-based I/O error: incorrect
>   checksum (expected: 0x3ee24b20;
>   actual: 0x8d0681bd). It occurred
>   during a read of page (1:375) in
>   database ID 1 at offset
>   0x000000002ee000 in file 'C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf'.
>   Additional messages in the SQL Server
>   error log or system event log may
>   provide more detail. This is a severe
>   error condition that threatens
>   database integrity and must be
>   corrected immediately. Complete a full
>   database consistency check (DBCC
>   CHECKDB). This error can be caused by
>   many factors; for more information,
>   see SQL Server Books Online.
>   2010-03-09 06:12:35.51 spid7s SQL
>   Trace was stopped due to server
>   shutdown. Trace ID = '1'. This is an
>   informational message only; no user
>   action is required.

How can I solve it?

Thank you!

Comment: Ok, I read through your wonderful suggestions. I've got a big problem,  I cannot connect to the database's instance. I can't even start the sql server service. Thereby, I cannot run sql management studio. I'm stuck! 

By the way, it's a first time deployment of my application. I've built it locally, and now trying to launch it on a vps...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like your master mdf file (master database) is corrupted.

Options include:
1. Restoring from backup
2. Detach existing databases (if possible), remove, and reinstall.

You might want to look a little deeper to see why this happened.  It might be a failing drive on that machine.  In which case, your number one priority is going to be to fix the hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Try DBCC with proper parameters (CHECKFILEGROUP). If that does not help.... try identifying whether the error is in an index (then you can recreate that).

Otherwise.... get the backups. You HAVE backups, or?? ;) (good test for those - could have been a real database, not just the mater)

As this is master...
...detach all databases, get a new master generated (if anything ails reinstall server), reattach databases.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, this [blog post](http://sureshbabum.blogspot.com/2011/03/sql-dba-corrupted-db-logical.html) helped me tremendously. Help this will benefit others who run into the same issue down the road.

You should read the article for detailed step-by-step process. But this is the key command.

> DBCC CheckTable ('corrupted_table', REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS)